# Write to databricks table from spark worker node

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

Can someone let me know if I can write to a databricks table directly from a worker node in Spark ? Please provide the code snippets. I am partitioning big data around 100 million records and hence it is failing due to memory issues when I issue a collect statement to get the data back into driver node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you are always writing from a Worker Node to a Databricks table. The collect should be avoided at all costs as you see - Driver OOM.

To avoid OOM issues you should do like most do, repartition your records so they fit inside the allowable partition sizes limit - 2GB or now 4GB with newer Spark releases, on your Worker Nodes and all well be fine. E.g.:

```
val repartitionedWikiDF = wikiDF.repartition(16) 
val targetPath = f"{workingDir}/wiki.parquet"
repartitionedwikiDF.write.mode("OVERWRITE").parquet(targetPath)
display(dbutils.fs.ls(targetPath))
```

You can also perform `df.repartition(col, N)`. There is also `range partitioning`.

Best approach is *like* this imo:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.repartition(col("country"))
  .write.partitionBy("country")
  .parquet("repartitionedPartitionedBy.parquet")
```

Comment: Shouldnt we try to write the repartitioned dataframe instead of the initial one ? Like this command ? --> repartitionedWikiDF.write.mode("OVERWRITE").parquet(targetPath)

Comment: indeed, a little late in the evening